# How can I open new pages in new UIWebViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'd like to open new web pages in new `UIWebViews`. For example, when you go to Google that would count as one web page, but when you click on Google Images within Google it would count as a new web page.

All new web pages will be loaded in new `UIWebViews` and will be put in a History array that contains all the `UIWebViews`.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward) {

        // The UIWebView already exists for that page in the history array, call it and display it.
    }
    else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted) {

        // No problem, load it in the current UIWebView.
    }
    else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {

        // It's a new page, load it in a new UIWebView.
    }
    else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        // It's a new page, load it in a new UIWebView
    }
    else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload) {

        // Just reload the current UIWebView.
    }
    else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {

        // There's no way this is a new page. Do nothing.
    }
}
```

As you probably have guessed, it didn't work. All you have to do is follow this path:

1. Go to http://www.9gag.com
2. Click the share on twitter icon under any post.

The link to share on twitter will look something like this:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2F9gag.com%2Fgag%2FaRQpqj2%3Fref%3Dt.mw&source=tweetbutton&text=I%20don%27t%20throw%20the%20word%20%27genius%27%20around%20loosely%2C%20but...&url=http%3A%2F%2F9gag.com%2Fgag%2FaRQpqj2%3Fref%3Dt.mw&via=9GAG
```

Although, someone would expect this link to be of type **LinkClicked** because you clicked the twitter icon to go there, it's actually of type **Other**, any desktop web browser will consider this link to be a pop up and would have opened it in a new window. Safari on iOS opens this link in a new tab. I would like to open it in a new `UIWebView` but **the problem is that there's nothing differentiating an ad request from a pop up request in the `UIWebView`'s delegate.**

How is Safari doing it?

**EDIT: The answer bellow is exactly the problem with `UIWebView`. It fools everyone into thinking that the delegate is the answer, when in fact you can do nothing without hacking your way through, even the simplest stuff.**

**EDIT 2: I have checked with other browsers as well like Mercury and they get this right. They understand that Twitter is a pop up and they open it in a new tab. So, this is not Apple's fault.**

Comment: This could possibly create some very high memory usage and will more then likely generate some memory warnings, if you have loads of `UIWebView`s going at once. Is this really the best way to be doing it?

Comment: The short answer is yes, it's possible with a bit of memory management but I would rather not argue on this.

Comment: That is some hell of memory management if you're creating a new `UIWebView` for every `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` you could have hundreds, I can see this getting rejected by Apple for memory issue, in all honest I would recommend rethinking your design here.

Comment: Seriously, a dozen of UIWebViews is all I need. 12 * 20MB = 240MB of RAM. You have to believe in me :)

Comment: A dozen webviews will still create issues. Try just creating a simple project and just add 5 webviews that load google up and see the memory jump through the roof.

Comment: Doesn't matter I have to stick with this architecture. :)

Comment: Also, Popeye I believe UIWebViews share their cache and perhaps 10 UIWebViews of Google will "weigh" less than 10 actual UIWebViews of Google.

Comment: You'll probably find that you will get memory warnings and more than likely a crash before you even reach 240MB once you get so high it will start to go extremely slow and as a user do you not think this would be very bad? I would.

Comment: I would assume that safari will have only 1 webview and will open a new tab like a normal browser would. This is how you should be doing it. Which I believe the webview should handle for you anyway if the site has been written to work like that as well.

Comment: Safari has 1 webview for every 1 tab. It should do some recycling after let's say 8 web views but anyway I think memory-wise it may look unifficent on the tiny iphone but as I said I prefer not to argue whether the memory management is possible or not.

Comment: You can try observe request when UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked. With regexp try to check url - if it contains word that you need -tweeter,Facebook, etc create new web view...

Comment: It's not 100% accurate for every web page in the world but hank you.

Comment: @user3737190 Please don't be offering users rewards in the form of money for answering your question like that. That isn't welcome here on stackoverflow, I have removed this from your question. When you get to a certain reputation you can give users some of your reputation to encourage them to give a correct answer but please don't offer money.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate of your first web view to your view controller.
After that, add the following code to your view controller.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);
    NSLog(@"%@", [request.URL scheme]);
    if ([[request.URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"])
    {
        // Create web view here, because you're catching all requests
        // Don't forget to set the delegate.
        NSLog(@"Create new web view with %@", request.URL);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

As you can see, you should replace the part where I added the NSLog. You're probably going to want to create a new web view at that point, and add it to the current view as a subview.

Why would you want to check on LinkClicked and not catch all requests?

Comment: Not sure this really helps this would create more memory issues as you're saying create a new `UIWebView` for every request instead of just ones for `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` and `UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted`. -1

Comment: This doesn't really help and Popeye this is not what I want to do. Let me explain, it's about new pages. Popup pages count as new pages but their type is not UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked nor UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted their type is (surprisingly) UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther although you clicked the link. :(

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I think you're stuck with Apple then. This is the way they implemented UIWebView, and I don't think there is any way to force 'link clicked' for popups. It might be that javascript opens the popup, so the link is not actually clicked.

Comment: As I mentioned above I checked with other third party browsers that don't get stuck there.